# Calling sudo within a script that was called with sudo prompts for password even with NOPASSWD

Tags: php, bash, httpd, perl, sudo

A PHP program I am working with ([LConf](https://www.netways.org/projects/lconf-for-icinga/wiki)) calls a script using `sudo`.

I have allowed the user `apache` to run the script and have tested with `sudo -u apache /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh`.

I am being prompted for a password when `lconf_deploy.sh` calls `/usr/bin/sudo -u icinga /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v`, but have no problems calling lines before or after this line.

After reading a lot (both on stackexchange and elsewhere on the internet) about what to do in this situation, I have disabled `requiretty` and used `NOPASSWD` for everything I can think of that affects this situation.

```
# cat /etc/sudoers | grep -v "#"
Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u icinga /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
icinga ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
```

Is it possible to switch user context (or whatnot) using `sudo`, while already "`sudoing`"?

If not, how do I solve this problem?  Note that `/usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl` must be run as the user `icinga`.

Thanks,

Matt

[updated with reference to mdpc's comment below]

```
   User_Alias      LCONF=apache,icinga
   Defaults:LCONF !requiretty
   LCONF ALL=(icinga) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/LconfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
   LCONF ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh
```

Executing `sudo -u apache /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh.` still prompts for password

```
   # cat  /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh
   echo start of script
   /usr/bin/sudo -u icinga /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
   /etc/init.d/icinga reload
   # sudo -u apache /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh
   start of script
   [sudo] password for apache:
   Running configuration check.../etc/init.d/icinga: line 111: /var/icinga/icinga.chk:      Permission denied
   CONFIG ERROR! Reload aborted. See /var/icinga/icinga.chk for details.
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   == mbrownnyc [266b4002@gateway] has joined ##linux
   -ChanServ- [##linux] Welcome to ##Linux! Can't speak? Please see http://linuxassist.net/irc on how to register or identify your nick. By joining this channel you agree to abide by the channel rules and guidelines stated on the official ##Linux website http://www.linuxassist.net/rules .
   <loomsen> there are different ways to solve this, but all of them are ugly and        discouraged
   <loomsen> mbrownnyc, you could add apache to the icinga group, make that script ug+x and set a sticky bit
   <nb-ben> mbrownnyc, you should take a look at suEXEC for php

   <koala_man> mbrownnyc: works fine: http://pastebin.com/JhefHzCh
   <koala_man> mbrownnyc: I still think you're just confusing your users
   <koala_man> mbrownnyc: you add permissions for apache to run lconf_deploy as        root, and then test using your icinga user
   <koala_man> to run it as apache
```

Solution:

```
   # cat /etc/passwd | grep icinga
   icinga:x:499:500:icinga:/var/icinga:/bin/false
   # cat /etc/passwd | grep apache
   apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/bin/false

   # grep -v "#" /etc/sudoers
   Defaults    !requiretty
   Defaults   !visiblepw
   Defaults    always_set_home
   Defaults    env_reset
   Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
   Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
   Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
   Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

   User_Alias      LCONF=apache,icinga
   Defaults:LCONF !requiretty

   LCONF ALL=(apache) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh
   LCONF ALL=(icinga) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v

   # cat /usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   echo start of script
   sudo -u icinga /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
   /etc/init.d/icinga reload
```

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
 apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo -u icinga /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
```

will not work.  It will invoke sudo as apache, and that is not right.

What you probably want is:

```
  apache ALL=(icinga) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v
```

Comment: I'll test this and let you know!  Thanks for the info.

Comment: NOTE:  You'll still have to invoke the sudo command while running the command as the apache user as: /usr/bin/sudo -u icinga /usr/local/LConf......

Comment: This did not work.  I've updated the question with relevant part of visudo.

Comment: You have made a spelling mistake, in the script LConf in sudo Lconf. If you copied my original line I made the same typos (which have been corrected). Sorry about that.

Comment: Corrected in /etc/sudoers and the original post.  Problem persists any ideas: `[sudo] password for apache:`  I have a feeling it's the calling of `sudo -u icinga` inside of the bash script that's the problem.  How can I verify that the environment is solid for sudoers to be accessed or what not?

Comment: The same thing occurs if I: `sudo -u apache sudo -u icinga /usr/local/LConf/LConfExport.pl -o /etc/icinga/lconf -v`

Comment: Why not try the following test, (0) su - root (1) su apache, (2) run id command, (3)/usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh.  This properly tests the environment as you'll be running the deploy.sh script as apache when running in the web right?  If this works then there is some problem with the initial testing methodology being used.

Comment: I just kicked this into freenode ##linux, and have updated the original question with some answers.

Answer (score 1):

Type

`su - apache`

Then

```
/usr/local/LConf/lconf_deploy.sh
```

If first command does not work type :

```
su - apache -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Eric.  I'd be executing the command via apache, since it is actually executing a shell script from some PHP code (that I don't control).  So there will be no interaction with the shell.